# Communicate two containers in docker with netcat

Tags: networking, docker, port, ping, netcat

I want to communicate two containers in docker, I'm using netcat for the test. First I have created the Dockefile:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install netcat iputils-ping -y
```

And added the image with:

```
docker build . -t ubuntu_netcat
```

Also I have created a new network:

```
docker network create --driver bridge nettest
```

Then I run two containers:

```
docker run --net=nettest --expose=8080 -it --name pc1 ubuntu_netcat
docker run --net=nettest --link=pc1 -it --name pc2 ubuntu_netcat
```

At first container (pc1) I listen on port 8080 with netcat command:

```
nc -vlk 8080
```

And I expect to communicate with it from the second container (pc2) executing:

```
nc -v pc1 8080
```

But I just got a connection refused:

```
root@c592b2015439:~# nc -v pc1 8080
pc1.nettest [172.18.0.2] 8080 (?) : Connection refused
```

I have been looking at the docker docs but all seems to be correct. In fact I can perform a ping between containers sucessfully, so they can reach one other, but I have something wrong with ports.
¿What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This helped me with a `docker network` question to link two Docker containers. Did you follow some blog to come up with this example, or come up with your own here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like this version of `netcat` on Ubuntu doesn't listen like it normally does. You have to specify `-p` for the port (even though the options would appear to have port as a positional option).

Your `netcat` listener command should be:

```
nc -vlkp 8080
```

Comment: You are right ! I was thinking it was docker configuration problem but the problem was at the netcat version. Thank you!

Comment: Avoid this and other similar issues by using netcat-openbsd